# Unit testing a Managed Service Factory or Service Component

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi, aries

Is there an sample of unit testing the creation of a SCR or MSF via ConfigAdmin without using pax-exam?

I'm looking to startup up my MSF or SCR.. then add the configuration entry and confirm the creation of the service.

Currently, I'm using the felix connect blueprint-test framework.

Comment: Did you look at bndtools? It has its own testing framework

Comment: I did, I was not able to find an example of running a test outside the Eclipse plugin. Link?

Comment: Writing integration test cases with JUnit is described in [OSGi enRoute](http://enroute.osgi.org/tutorial_base/600-testing.html). You might want to follow the whole tutorial.